# Sidebar menu messes up the responsiveness of semantic cards

Tags: css, angularjs, semantic-ui

I'm using `semantic-ui` as my site ui framework, alongside `angular 1.5.8`.

What happens when the sidebar is visible is that the browser must hide nearly 50% of the card, within a `ui cards` dive, before the card responsively moves to a new row.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="pushable">
    <div class="ui left vertical inverted visible thin sidebar menu">
      <a class="item">
              Overview
          </a>
      <a class="item">
              Upcoming
          </a>
    </div>

    <div class="pusher">
      <div style="margin: 20px;" class="ui cards">
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="bill in bills">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="header">
              {{bill.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="meta">
              {{bill.biller}}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="extra content">
            <div class="ui two buttons">
              <div class="ui basic green button">Edit</div>
              <div class="ui basic red button">Delete</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image]

If I remove the `visible` class from the sidebar div, then it works as expected. As soon as the browser window chrome gets close to the border of the card, the card wraps to a new row. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to manually account for the size of the sidebar myself? It doesn't seem like I would have to, considering the cards and sidebar are both `semantic-ui` components.

I've got a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U7IuRq?p=preview) demonstrating this issue as well.

Comment: I also have this issue, did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html

> A container can be used alongside a grid to provide a responsive, fixed width container for wrapping the contents of a page.

Add the container class to your to your cards div to make it responsive.